# Was there a word for cleavage, decolleté, or decolletage in the 17th century?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, seventeenth-century-english

I'm particularly interested in finding a word used in the 17th century that was more specific than bosom. I could find no use of cleavage before the 20th century or decolleté before 1778.

Interested in slang words for the narrow depression or hollow between the breasts of a woman. I am wanting to find a word to use in a work of historical fiction set in the 17th century. I want one character to describe the appearance of a woman with a very visible cleavage.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/600895/was-cleavage-first-used-for-jane-russell

Comment: **Stomacher** *- a piece of clothing that covered a woman's chest, but it could also be used to refer to the area of a woman's chest that was visible between her neckline and her stomacher.*

Comment: I can find a number of slang words, but nothing clinical. Are you looking for a colloquial word? Also, are we referring to the clothing, the area, or to the breasts themselves?

Comment: Google Bard suggests **paps**, but that was always a bit coarse. And **décolletage**, of which it says *This French word was not commonly used in English during Shakespeare's time, but **it was starting to become popular.***

Comment: @Heartspring Interested in colloquial words, referring to part of the body.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I couldn't find an example of décolletage being used before 1778 on Google Books English language results.

Comment: @Bob516: I wouldn't trust Google Books much for any texts more than a couple of centuries old, *especially* if the text includes non-English accents! Also, don't forget that the names of significantly *sexual* parts of the body are likely to involve far more changes over time and between regions than most nouns, for what I hope are obvious reasons. And I'm sure that would be *particularly* true of "slang" terms. You don't say why you're asking, but if it's to use in some historical fiction narrative, I suggest "accuracy" is far less important than "sounds plausible to non-specialists".

Comment: You could be more precise: "referring to part of the body" doesn't help. Upper chest? Specifically the gap between the breasts? The curved form of the bosom? The area visible in the front of a low-cut dress of some shape or other? Some part of the form of breasts pushed together and up? Got a picture or diagram? You're also supposed to do research before posting - say what you've already found or considered.

Comment: Could you explain why you need to know this?  You have correctly found out that the word is not attested much before the latter third of the 18th century.  It, or equivalent words are unlikely to have been in literary use much before that time, other than in the relatively rare erotic literature.

Comment: @Tuffy If such a word exists in erotic literature I think it might be of value to me. I edited my question to explain why I am looking for such a word. I might read through The School of Venus by Michel Millot, 1655, for help.

Answer (score 4):

Etymonline suggests the term [decoloured](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search_field=hnf&q=decoloured) (Cut low at the neck, décolleté.)

[Décolleté](https://www.etymonline.com/word/decollete)

> Middle English had an equivalent and partially nativized adjective, decoloured (mid-15c.).

Answer (score 3):

##### Poetic: *Globes*

pre-1705:

> BREASTS
> With what rich **Globes** did her soft Bosom swell?
> Plump as ripe Clusters rose each glowing Breast,
> Courting the Hand, and suing to be press'd.
> The yielding Marble of her snowy Breast.
> Thy little Breasts with soft compassion swell'd
> Shov'd up and down, and heav'd like dying Birds.
>
> <sub>Translation of Ovid, by a 'Mr. Duke'. Found in *[The Art of English Poetry Vol. 3](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Art_of_English_Poetry/tndIMP22cskC?hl=en&gbpv=0)*</sub>

pre-1727

> Once, I remember, as your flowing Vest
> Disclos'd the naked Wonders of your Breast,
> How meltingly the snowy **Globes** arose!
> Fair, as the Fleeces of descending Snows!
>
> <sub>Seemingly a translation of Ovid, by William Pattison. Found in *[The Poetical Works of Mr. William Pattison](https://xtf.lib.virginia.edu/xtf/view?docId=chadwyck_ep/uvaGenText/tei/chep_2.1782.xml&chunk.id=d89&toc.id=d89&brand=default)*</sub>

1777:

> The swelling beauties of the Female breast!
> Soft **Semi-Globes**, by bounteous Heaven defign'd,
> To pour nectareous juices, fweet, refin'd!
>
> <sub>William Combe. Found in [*The Semi Globes, Or Electrical Orbs*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Semi_Globes_Or_Electrical_Orbs/2QF-Y27SdF0C?hl=en&gbpv=0)</sub>

---

##### Slang: *Bubbies*

1709:

> I would hardly draw them from under my Morning-gown, to play with Helen's delicious **Bubbies**, which undoubtedly were very commendable Bubbies, since, in Conjunction with her Face, they made the Greeks and Trojans deal their handy Blows to liberally to one another.
>
> <sub>Thomas Brown. Found in satirical text *[The Works: In Prose and Verse. Serious, Moral, & Comical](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Works/Ec9LAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)*</sub>

1725:

> Others standing as Spectators to delight their Eyes with the fine Cuts and Capers of the young Mercurial Gentlemen, and the silent Tread and swimming Deportment of the nimble-footed Ladies, who seem'd equally industrious to win Hearts by the pouting of their **Bubbies**, the wriggle of their Bums, and the activity of their Pettitoes.
>
> <sub>E. W. Found in  *[The Amorous Bugbears: Or, the Humours of a Masquerade](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Amorous_Bugbears_Or_the_Humours_of_a/XzdcAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)*</sub>

1739:

> By the Mole on your **Bubbies**, so round and so white; By the Mole on your Neck...
>
> Thy fresh ruddy Lips, and thy Teeth all so white,
> Thy round tempting **Bubbies**, which heave with Delight, ....
>
> <sub>Found in  *[The Cupid: A Collection of Love Songs, in Twelve Parts](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Cupid_A_Collection_of_Love_Songs_in/2V9gAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)*</sub>

---

**Note:** This was posted before the OP added their clarifications to the question; their [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/615091/was-there-a-word-for-cleavage-decollet%C3%A9-or-decolletage-in-the-17th-century/615098#comment1563574_615091) saying "Interested in colloquial words, referring to part of the body" *seemed*, at the time, to validate this answer. (The answer received 3 upvotes before the edits.) Now that we know that the OP is looking for a term for 'cleavage', this doesn't fit quite so nicely anymore. However, the OP left comments under some of the other answers, explaining why those ones didn't work. Since they've yet to do so under mine, I am waiting for the OP to declare this as overly tangential/not helpful before I delete it.

Comment: globes just means breasts and does not refer to cleavage.

Comment: No understanding as to how this was flagged LQ.  It does attempt to answer the question in every way, including supporting citations. Disagreeing with it (or any answer not "just right") does not make it LQ.  Vote; don't flag.

Comment: @Heartspring OP specifically asked about cleavage, not for a poetic discourse on what was cloven.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd - yeah... This answer was made before the OP added all those clarifications. I was going off of the original question, and a comment that said "_Interested in colloquial words, referring to part of the body_".

Comment: @livresque - it was probably flagged as NAA (see comments above), which sends it to the same queue.

Comment: @Heartspring - I loved your answer and up-voted it because it was so deliciously informative.  Without 'globes' or 'bubbies' there would be no cleavage.

Answer (score -1):

> I'm particularly interested in finding a word used in the 17th century that was more specific than bosom. I could find no use of cleavage before the 20th century or decolleté before 1778.

You will not find an answer. "Cleavage", in this sense, did not exist as a concept prior to 1946.

Cleavage is defined by the OED as **2.b.The cleft between a woman's breasts as revealed by a low-cut décolletage.** *colloquial*.

It is first recorded as "jargon":

> 1946 Low-cut Restoration costumes..display too much ‘cleavage’ (Johnston Office trade term for the shadowed depression dividing an actress' bosom into two distinct sections). *Time 5 August 98*

The Johnston in question was Eric Johnston, president of the Motion Picture Association of America, amongst whose duties was that of imposing the Motion Picture Production Code on film-makers. This code stated what could, and what could not, be shown on film.

The term "cleavage" can thus be seen as a euphemism for "breasts" as a cleavage, in this sense, cannot exist without breasts.

Comment: What do you mean the concept did not exist prior to 1946?  There was no awareness of that aspect of women's anatomy before the word was coined by the Johnson Office?

Comment: Are you aware I am the OP?

Comment: Ha! No. In that case: "Cleavage" existed in several meanings prior to c. 1946, but not in the sense that you want. What we now call "cleavage/a cleavage" was not a concept that anyone had thought to describe - hence there was no word. The cleavage is the line separating the breasts and only by implication is it associated with breasts. "[A] cleavage" doesn't refers directly to "breasts": it's purpose is to avoid that mention. Not so much a euphemism, more a "polite misdirection".

Answer (score -2):

From Wikipedia:

> Women started squeezing the breasts and applying make up to make their cleavage more attractive;[39] cleavage was termed the "smile of the bustline" by contemporaneous Belgian chronicler Jean Froissart.

Comment: From where on Wikipedia? You need to cite the exact page.

Comment: That's a translation from French...